# Reproduce Capturing iteration variable issue

Tags: c#, closures, c#-5.0

I'm rereading a part from c# 5.0 in Nutshell about the capturing iteration variables (Page 138)  and I have tried to reproduce the code bellow on  c#  4.0 and c# 5.0 but with no hope to catch  the difference until now

```
using System;
class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {      
        Action[] actions = new Action[3];
        int i = 0;
        foreach (char c in "abc")
            actions[i++] = () => Console.Write(c);
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            actions[j]();
        }
        foreach (Action a in actions) a();    
        Console.ReadLine(); 
    }
}
```

***Note***
*I have Visual studio 2012(.net 4.0 and 4.5 installed)  and I have changed the target framework while trying to reproduce the issue*

**Update**
to explain more the issue  the output with c# 4.0 will be different from c# 5.0
I Know this may be less useful due to update to a recent version of C# Compiler

can anyone enlighten  me on how to reproduce this issue ?

Comment: what are trying to reproduce?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't reproduce it because you are changing the version of the .Net framework but not the compiler. You're always using C# v5.0 which fixes the issue for `foreach` loops. You can see the issue with `for` loops though:

```
Action[] actions = new Action[3];
int i = 0;

for (int j = 0; j < "abc".Length; j++)
    actions[i++] = () => Console.Write("abc"[j]);
for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
{
    actions[j]();
}
foreach (Action a in actions) a();
Console.ReadLine();
```

To use the old compiler you need an old VS version. In this case to see your code break with `foreach` you need to test it in VS 2010 (I did locally).

---

You might want to try to change the language version of the compiler (as xanatos suggested in the comments) but that doesn't use an old compiler. It uses the same compiler but limits you to using specific features:

> Because each version of the C# compiler contains extensions to the language specification, `/langversion` does not give you the equivalent functionality of an earlier version of the compiler.

From [/langversion (C# Compiler Options)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f4ckecs0.aspx)

Comment: @ I got this in mind but is there anything that can justify your answer

Comment: @i3arnon But why if I change the Language Version in Properties->Build->Advanced it still works?

Comment: @xanatos You're still using the C# 5.0 compiler. Refer my answer. Eric blogged about it.

Comment: @KamelBRAHIM You need to run your code in VS 2010 to see the difference. I've checked it locally but I can't find an online compiler for v4.0

Comment: @i3arnon your code will not compile at all  because the j  will be captured when  it's  equal 3 which cause IndexOutOfRangeException

Comment: @KamelBRAHIM That's not what compiling means. It throws an exception becuase `j == 3` because it was captured. Otherwise it would be 0, 1 or 2. The exception is the thing that proves the difference.

Comment: @i3arnon I completely agree

Answer (score 3):

Because this issue has been fixed in C# compiler 5.0, you can't reproduce it with Visual studio 2012.

You need to use the C# compiler version 4.0 to reproduce the issue which author is trying to explain. With Visual studio 2010 you can reproduce the problem.

Even if you change the Language version in Vs2012, it still won't work. because [you're still using the C# 5.0 compiler](http://ericlippert.com/2013/04/04/what-does-the-langversion-switch-do/).

Comment: Fascinating! Really fascinating... quite an useless feature then :) (the langversion switch I mean)

Comment: @xanatos And it is not intuitive. Misleading name for the feature :)

Comment: @SriramSakthivel is there anything  in IL code that say that the code was generated by c# 5.0  compiler

Comment: @KamelBRAHIM I'm afraid. There is none(at least I know).

Answer (score 0):

This behavior had been changed for `foreach` loops since 4.0. But you can reproduce it with a `for` loop:

```
static void Main()
{      
    Action[] actions = new Action[3];
    int i = 0;
    for (var c = 0; c < 3; c++)
        actions[i++] = () => Console.Write(c);
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
    {
        actions[j]();
    }
    foreach (Action a in actions) a();    
    Console.ReadLine(); 
}
```

Output: "333333"