# Are previous versions of C# compiler just an emulation in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, c#-5.0

C#5 introduced a breaking change to the way closures over the loop variable work in the `foreach` statement, that is well known (details can be found in [this](http://ericlippert.com/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful-part-one/) article by Eric Lippert). I wanted to see the pre-breaking change behaviour in Visual Studio. For that I created a small Console App with this code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var values = new List<int>() { 100, 110, 120 };
            var funcs = new List<Func<int>>();
            foreach (var v in values)
                funcs.Add(() => v);
            foreach (var f in funcs)
                Console.WriteLine(f());
        }
        //this method does break compilation on C# versions that are older than C#5  
        public async void DoStuff()
        {
            
        }        
    }
}
```

When compiled with C#5 compiler it obviously printed

```
110
120
130
```

But after I went to `Project|Properties|Build|Advanced`, changed compiler to C#3 and commented the `DoStuff` method it still printed the same numbers, not

```
130
130
130
```

as I expected it to.

After that I investigated the IL-codes for the `Main` methods produced by both compilers and they were perfectly identical.

So my question is: are different language versions of C# that I can choose in Visual Studio actually all the last version of the compiler with some language features being restricted and if so, what is the reason for this decision?

Comment: Language version switch doesn't do what you think it does. Refer [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28961937/2530848) in the duplicate question for details.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel thanks! That's a pity I didn't find that myself.

Comment: No worries. It is really hard to find. I found it easily just because I answered it :)

Comment: See also http://ericlippert.com/2013/04/04/what-does-the-langversion-switch-do/